# How to add column on Prestashop cart summary from a module

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need a method for modifying the cart summary page from inside a Prestashop module.
Basically I want a new column with a select box, and after the client clicks the Proceed to Checkout button I want to fetch the option selected for each product.
Also, altering the theme is not an option, I am trying to accomplish this inside a module.
[image: Prestashop Cart Summary]

Answer (score 0):

Since altering the theme is not an option you can "inject" the required markup code with JavaScrit - for example with jQuery.

Take a look at the "after()" method.

http://api.jquery.com/after/